# Changing data in bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

I'm working on jeopardy game where I pass questions into a bootstrap modal based on the button clicked. The button has an attribute data-num, (the index in the array of questions), which is used to to change the title in the modal. It also passes this index as an attribute data-num to the reveal answer button, which, when clicked, will change modal title to the answer.

This works for the first question, but when I click on the second question, the proper question loads, but the answer to the first question loads when I click the getanswer button, even though the proper index shows up in inspect element under button data-num.
 What am I doing wrong?

```js
var questions = [{
    prompt: "What generic data type should we use when we want to use varying data types for a variable?",
    correctAnswer: "Object",
  },
  {
    prompt: "Rewrite the following Javascript statment in C#: var flag = true ",
    correctAnswer: "bool flag = true"
  },
  {
    prompt: "double num1 = 9.34534910;\n int num2= (int)num1;\nSystem.Console.WriteLine(num2);",
    correctAnswer: "9"
  }
];

function showQuestion(event, $modal) {
  var button = $(event.relatedTarget);
  var num = parseInt(button.data('num'));
  var question = questions[num];
  $modal.find('.modal-title').text(question.prompt);
  $modal.find('.modal-body button').attr('data-num', num)
}

$("#myModal").on('show.bs.modal', function(event) {
    showQuestion(event, $(this));
  }
);

$("#myModal").on('hidden.bs.modal', function() {
    $('#myModal').removeData('bs.modal');
  }
);

$("#getanswer").click(function() {
    var num = ($(this).data('num'));
    console.log(num)
  }
)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="bs-example">
  <!-- Modal HTML -->
  <div id="myModal" class="modal fade">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-body">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
          <p class="modal-title" data-answer="">Modal Window</p>
          <button id="getanswer" type="button" data-num="" class="btn btn-primary clickable">Reveal answer</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="question">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info gridbtn ten" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" data-num="0">$10</button>
  </div>
  <div class="question">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info gridbtn fifty" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" data-num="1">$50</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: where's the HTML that launches the modal?

Comment: Both of the buttons at the bottom of the HTML, in the the "questions" divs. Then the #getanswer button inside the modal retrieves the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this (on the #getAnswer click event):

```
var num = ($(this).attr('data-num'));
```

instead of

```
var num = ($(this).data('num'));
```

Perhaps since you set the value with attr, it also works to retrieve it that way.

It DOES seem like your way should work, but this is what I found through trying stuff.

Comment: accept my answer if you like it. :) (you don't have to of course if you have reasons for not wanting to)

Comment: Sorry! New to posting questions!